# Bigquery - how to make a column true when month of date column matches with other date column?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table like this,

```
id  date        start       end         product     result

10  2022-06-10  2022-02-10  2022-06-12  183         TRUE
10  2022-06-11  2022-02-10  2022-06-12  183         TRUE
10  2022-06-12  2022-02-10  2022-06-12  183         TRUE
10  2022-06-13  null        null        183         FALSE
10  2022-06-14  null        null        183         FALSE
......
10  2022-04-01  null        null        183         FALSE
```

So, I want the column 'result' as TRUE when year and month of 'date' column matches the year and month of 'end' column with null values.

i.e for each date (month and year) in 'date' column,  look through all rows in 'end' column with same month and year and if the month and year matches, then make frozen as TRUE.

i.e, The final result should look like this,

```
id  date        start       end         product     result

10  2022-06-10  2022-02-10  2022-06-12  183         TRUE
10  2022-06-11  2022-02-10  2022-06-12  183         TRUE
10  2022-06-12  2022-02-10  2022-06-12  183         TRUE
10  2022-06-13  null        null        183         TRUE
10  2022-06-14  null        null        183         TRUE
......
10  2022-07-01  null        null        183         FALSE
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: To remove the day from the fields, please use `date_trunc(date,month)=date_trunc(end,month)`. Please also consider what to do with `null` values e.g. `or end is  null `

Comment: Thanks and yes quite not sure how to handle those null values. Any idea of how to check preceding dates?

Comment: The preceding dates would be new question. As yours is already answered. The date of a previous record can be used by  `lag(column_name) over (order by time_column)` ; please search for BigQuery windows function then.

Comment: Thank you. Sure, I have edited the question hope its clear now.

Comment: Your latest edit made the question less clear. The sentence you added is confusing and potentially completely changes the meaning of the question. Maybe explain what it is that you are actually doing with this code

Comment: Have edited the question hope it's clear. Also, I have already attached the expected solution for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider the below approach for bigquery.

```
select *,
case
when date is not null and 
end is not null and 
date_trunc(date,month) = date_trunc(end,month)
then "TRUE" 
else "FALSE" 
end as New_Result
from Data
```

I've added in a check for nulls to return a false result if either date or end has a null value, but you could seperate this to flag these instances if needed like below.

```
select *,
case
    when date is null or end is null then "CHECK ME"
    when date_trunc(date,month) = date_trunc(end,month) then "TRUE" 
    else "FALSE" 
end as New_Result,
from Data
```

Comment: Thanks, anyhow I need it as TRUE for the same month by comparing the preceding dates.

Comment: That wasn't specified in your question, and is a completely different question. You'll need to use window functions to achieve that, but should be asked in a new request since this current question has been answered.

Comment: Sure, but the provided solution doesn't seem to solve the question yet.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score -1):

What about using alias when querying:

`SELECT id, date, start, end, productid, (date=end) as result FROM ProductTable;`

Hereby you will get the boolean result of date=end as the last column, when you query.